# Dynamic size animation of parent div using CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to trigger a parent div size transition by making the child div disappear via `display:none`

My assumption was - to create a dynamically centering div, that's also animated by using transitions. **I'm looking for a CSS only solution.**

Here is my approach.

```js
document.querySelector('#one').onclick = function () {
    document.querySelector('#two').classList.add("hidden")
}
```

```css
#content {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#one, #two {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

#one {
  background-color: cyan;
}

#two {
  background-color: magenta;
}

.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="centered">
  <div id="one">PRESS ME</div>
  <div id="two">TO MAKE ME DISAPPEAR</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Does not have to be `display:none` in the provided solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Steve's answer, I've managed to find a solution to the problem.
The following snippet is almost the same with his solution, however, the `transition` is set to height instead, so, `opacity: 0` happens instantly.

This solves the problem, as, height transition needs a previously defined height (which we have for the child element) that helps with the transition animation, also, using `opacity: 0` to make the content invisible instantly creates the trick of auto-centering parent content.

```js
document.querySelector('#one').onclick = function () {
 document.querySelector('#two').classList.add("hidden")
}
```

```css
.centered {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-right: -50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#one, #two {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

#one {
  background-color: cyan;
}

#two {
  background-color: magenta;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
}

#two.hidden {
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="centered">
  <div id="one">PRESS ME</div>
  <div id="two">TO MAKE ME DISAPPEAR</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't transition with `display:none` because the transition has no point of reference but you can do it with height.  Also you would want your transition to be on the element that you are trying to hide.  Then the parent div will shrink because the element is no longer in it.  Like so:

```js
document.querySelector('#one').onclick = function () {
 document.querySelector('#two').classList.add("hidden")
}
```

```css
.centered {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-right: -50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#one, #two {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

#one {
  background-color: cyan;
}

#two {
  background-color: magenta;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#two.hidden {
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="centered">
  <div id="one">PRESS ME</div>
  <div id="two">TO MAKE ME DISAPPEAR</div>
</div>
```

If you need the parent element to be the div that needs to be animated then you would use a height adjustment on the parent div.  So since you have 2 divs of 150px then give your `#content` div a height of 300px and then transition that div to 150px.  Also you would want to add the class of hidden to the `#content` div and then give `#two` a display of none.  Like so:

```js
document.querySelector('#one').onclick = function () {
 document.querySelector('#content').classList.add("hidden")
}
```

```css
#content {
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border:5px solid #000;
  height:300px;
}

.centered {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-right: -50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#one, #two {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

#one {
  background-color: cyan;
}

#two {
  background-color: magenta;
}

#content.hidden {
  height:150px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#content.hidden #two{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="centered">
  <div id="one">PRESS ME</div>
  <div id="two">TO MAKE ME DISAPPEAR</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wasn't as fast as Steve K! Good answer.

Comment: This animated the disappearance of the element I want to hide, instead, i visually want to make the centering process animated but disappearance process instant.

Comment: I edited my answer let me know if this is what your looking for.  If you are going to have any kind of dynamic heights or content then you would be better off using jquery but it you are going to fixed heights like you have in your example my second example in the answer that I edited will work for you

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. If I set the height of the parent div then it's not dynamic any more... All this, is to make a dynamically readjusting centering animation for the parent div.

Comment: You cant do that through css only you will need a javascript alternative like jquery to do this as far as i am aware.  Css transitions require a point of reference so you need to go from something to something to create the animation. With dynamically created content you have no initial reference point so the animation doesn't know where to start and end that is why you cant use it with display:none or auto heights.  Its not a big deal but for future reference this is something that should be stated in the original question because it is a key piece to the puzzle.